# Deep Reinforcement Learning that takes action from two different sets

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deep-rl, dqn, gym

I am working on a problem where I want to schedule multiple activities `(a1, a2, a3, ... aN)` requiring different resource types `(r1, r2, r3, ... rK)`, in order to get a minimum lifespan. Now, each resource type `rk` has `urk` independent units available for work, each having unique characteristics. I want to solve this problem using deep reinforcement learning but I am not clear how to create output layer such that the action signifies both which activity to pick - `a2`, along with which resource units - `[r11, r14, r23, r25, r31]` (considering a2 requires r1, r2, and r3 resource types. r11, and r14 being selected indicates their overall performance score is better than r12, and r13)

Comment: You have tagged this question with `dqn`. It is going to be very hard, maybe impossible, to deal with the flexibility of actions in DQN. Could you please clarify whether you want to fit this to a DQN agent, and give some estimate of the action space. For example if there are four main actions and five independently chosen resources allowed for each action, your action space would be 4 x 32 or 128. That number is still ok in DQN, but much higher would be a problem

Comment: No, I don't necessarily need to fit the model with DQN agent. I also started with the same thought to use DQN agent but later realized the same point you mentioned. So my thought went in a direction something like I could have 2 outputs : activity to choose as an integeter, and resource units selected as a boolean array [r11, r12, r13, r21, r22, r23, ... rkurk]